# Rearranging spreadsheet data

Tags: microsoft-excel, iwork-numbers

If I have the following data table:

```
Country    1990   2000   2010   LEB 1990   LEB 2000   LEB 2010
Afghanistan  15  17.72  18.24      48.60      54.86      59.61
...
```

How would I in an automated manner, convert it to the following (on Windows, OS X, web ...)?

```
Country      Year    LEB
Afghanistan  1990  48.60
Afghanistan  2000  54.86
Afghanistan  2010  59.61
...
```

Comment: macro  How is your VBA programming?

Comment: Try a pivot table!

Comment: Which program? Do you have the data already in a file format?

Comment: I have the data in csv/Numbers/Excel file format and I have access to both Excel and Numbers (and Open Office), so which program doesn't really matter that much. I have no knowledge of VBA. Can someone tell me why it's voted down?

Answer (score 0):

In MS Excel... Copy the row, right click, select "Paste Special," tick the "Transpose" box at the top of the column where you want to the data to appear, and click OK. You may need to clean up the text a bit afterward but it will certainly save you some time.